# Show the uploaded file on the home page

Tags: html

I want the picture I uploaded here to appear on the home page of the site. How can I do it?

```html
<input type="file" name="dosya" accept="image/*">
```

Comment: Please visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask]. ***[Do some research](https://www.google.com/search?q=javascript+preview+image+site:stackoverflow.com)***, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output using the `[<>]` snippet editor.

Comment: If you mean "Show image I uploaded from server after I uploaded it", then you need to tell us what server you are using but first [do some research](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52752054/upload-image-and-view-it-after-uploading)